# Проблема с записью в таблицу

Tags: java, j2ee

Друзья, у меня возникла проблема. Я считываю массив с файла и потом должен занести его в таблицу (JTable).Но вместо этого выводит нули. Как я понимаю , оно не может достать данные . Помогите разобраться.

```
Файл:
2 2 2
4 5 4
7 8 6
```

Код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class  LabSixSecond extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    private JFrame wnd;
    private float w, q, p;
    private int i;
    private JButton start, stop, apply;
    private JLabel nl, wl;
    private JTextField ntf, wtf;
    JTextArea txaSome = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea txaSome1 = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea txaSome2 = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea txaSome3 = new JTextArea();

    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;


    JButton btnSome = new JButton("Load file");

    final String THE_FILE = "D:\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.2\\works\\src\\Array6.txt"; // адрес к читаемому файлу
   // private static List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    int [][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabSixSecond();
    }

    private Object[] headers = new String[] {"x0", "x1", "x2"};
    LabSixSecond(){
        wnd = new JFrame("Array");
        wnd.setLayout(null);
        wnd.setSize(500, 500);
        wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wnd.setBounds(100, 50, 300, 300);
        btnSome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //обработчик события
                                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {



                                          File file = new File(THE_FILE);
                                          String str = "";
                                          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                                          //---------------------------------------------------
                                          try{
                                          Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.2\\\\works\\\\src\\\\Array6.txt")));

                                          while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                              for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
                                                  String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                                                  for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
                                                      myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                          System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
                                              txaSome.setText(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
                                          } catch (IOException exc) {
                                              exc.printStackTrace();
                                          }
                                          for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                                              int k = 1;
                                              for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length - 1; j++) {

                                                  if (myArray[i][j] == myArray[i][j + 1]) {
                                                      k += 1;
                                                      if (k == myArray[i].length) {
                                                          System.out.println("element:" + myArray[i][j]);
                                                          System.out.println("# of row:" + i);
                                                          txaSome1.setText("element:" + myArray[i][j]);
                                                          txaSome2.setText("# of row:" + i);
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }

                                          for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                                              int k = 1;
                                              for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)

                                                  if (myArray[j][i] % 2 != 0)
                                                      k = 0;

                                              if (k == 1) {
                                                  System.out.println("# of column:" + i);
                                                  txaSome3.setText("# of column:" + i);
                                              }


                                          }

                                          }
                                      }
                                      );



        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        Vector<Vector<Integer>> data = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();

        Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Integer> row = new Vector<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            header.add((String)headers[j]);

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray[j].length; i++) {
                row.add(myArray[j][i]);
            }
            data.add(row);


        }

        JTable table3 = new JTable(data, header);

        Box contents3 = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);


        table3.setForeground(Color.red);
        table3.setSelectionForeground(Color.yellow);
        table3.setSelectionBackground(Color.blue);

        table3.setShowGrid(true);
        contents3.add(table3);

        wnd.setContentPane(contents3);
        setSize(500, 400);
//---------------------------------------------------


        wnd.add(table3);
        wnd.add(txaSome);
        wnd.add(txaSome1);
        wnd.add(txaSome2);
        wnd.add(txaSome3);
        wnd.add(btnSome);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        wnd.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

(Там дополнительно у меня два циклы для того,что бы выводил номер рядка которого все элементы равны и номер столбца у которого все элементы четные)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас просто огромное количество бесполезного кода (в т.ч. неиспользуемых переменных). Код вполне ужасный, это делает практически невозможным его отладку. Я не знаю, зачем вам потребовался свинг, но в любом случае вьюхи такого рода никто руками не пишет. Это все делается в визуальной среде. При работе с таблицами для отрисовки в них данных проще всего использовать специальный класс DefaultTableModel, как я и сделал. Также я не уверен, что ваш путь к файлу корректный,поэтому перенесите свой файл в корневой каталог проекта (именно такой путь я указал в своем коде). Так что если после нажатия на кнопку загрузки файла увидите пустую таблицу, а в консоли File not found : java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Array6.txt, то это означает, что путь к вашему файлу некорректный. В остальном примерно это должно выглядеть так:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class LabSixSecond extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JButton buttonLoad;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTable table;
    private final String fileName = "Array6.txt";
    private final String[] titles = new String[]{"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"};

    public LabSixSecond() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        table = new JTable();
        buttonLoad = new JButton("Load file");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14));
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null}
                },
                titles
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class[]{String.class, String.class, String.class};

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);
        buttonLoad.addActionListener(this::jButton1ActionPerformed);
        GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(buttonLoad)
                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(buttonLoad)
                        .addGap(0, 138, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultTableModel createTableModel = createTableModel(titles);
        table.setModel(createTableModel);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel createTableModel(String... titles) {
        return new DefaultTableModel(read(), titles);
    }

    private String[][] read() {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream.map(line -> line.split(" ")).toArray(String[][]::new);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found : " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new LabSixSecond().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у Вас загрузка данных идет в обработчике события кнопки (который отрабатывает при нажатии на кнопку), а заполнение таблицы - в конструкторе. Но в конструкторе загрузки данных не происходит, поэтому таблица заполняется нулями.
Вам нужно вынести в отдельный метод все, что в обработчике кнопки и этот же метод вызвать в конструкторе перед заполнением JTable.
При заполнении таблицы у вас тоже ошибочка: переместите строку `Vector<Integer> row = new Vector<>();` перед внутренним циклом, а то в таблицу постоянно добавляются данные, а нужно для каждой строки новый вектор.